# Accesing JSON array inside of multiple arrays and objects

Tags: arrays, json, object

How can I access the "coordinates in my following JSON data? I have tried multiple ways, but I guess I am making errors since there are so many arrays and objects inside of each other. I wish to show the coordinates on a map. The data can be found here: https://citynature.eu/api/wp/v2/places?cityid=5

Here is a link to a picture of the data structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWVG2.png

Comment: How did you try to extract the coordinates? Please show your code.

Comment: for example: 

let coordinates = [];

  for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    array = mapdata[j];
    path_coordinates = array.routes.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0]

    coordinates.push([Number(path_coordinates[1]), Number(path_coordinates[0])]);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
    L.marker(coordinates[i]).addTo(mymap);
  };

Comment: Check iteration on coordinates in my answer below. As far as your code is concerned, check this working [example](https://repl.it/@AzeemSajid/mapDataIteration1).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with a smaller subset of your JSON ([live](https://repl.it/@AzeemSajid/mapDataIteration)):

```
const json = [
  {
    "ID": 626,
    "title": "Harakka",
    "url": "https://citynature.eu/fi/kohde/harakka/",
    "routes": {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {},
          "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                24.957525730133057,
                60.151828145666684
              ],
              [
                24.95747208595276,
                60.15161455386026
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
];

const coordinates = json[0].routes.features[0].geometry.coordinates;

let coords = [];

for ( let i = 0; i < coordinates.length; ++i )
{
  coords.push( coordinates[i][0], coordinates[i][1] );
}

// console.log("Coordinates: [" + coords + "]");

console.log("Coordinates:");

for ( let i = 0; i < coords.length; ++i )
{
  console.log( coords[i] );
}
```

Output:

```
Coordinates:
24.957525730133057
60.151828145666684
24.95747208595276
60.15161455386026
```